# Open layer 3 + how make it behave like google map when mouse scroll

Tags: openlayers-3

Google maps API show a message over the map when user scroll with mouse over the map. 
The message advice the user must press control key while scroll with mouse over map. 
This is a very nice solution to preserve normal page scroll with the mouse.

How can We do this in open layer 3+ API. Is thus possible? Please a need this behavior.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction  This URL is the link to behavior on google map We want to get here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answers to your questions:

1. How to detect that the user is doing scroll on the map with the mouse and show an alert that you must press control key?

   ```
   map.on('wheel', function(){
          //write whatyou like and add it in popup window
    });
   ```

   2. How can you make it so the zoom on the map can only be done by pressing control in addition to scrolling with the mouse?

OpenLayers doesn't have this functionality but you can do it by changing ol.js as you want.

A helpful similar function can be found [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/7666)

Also, you can do it with only (shift key) or (alt key)

```
     map.on('wheel', function(evt) {
            map.on('wheel', function(evt) {
    wheelZoom(evt);
});
function wheelZoom(evt) {
      if (ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(evt) !== true) {
          evt.browserEvent.preventDefault();
      }
  };
```

Comment: I've found another user friendly way to combine page and map scrolling by only zooming the map on wheel/trackpad scroll when it has the focus. I have created a pull request to make it easier to configure the map that way: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/7904.

Comment: @ahocevar I already mentioned this link in my answer, Also, the link doesn't give you a notification when the user tries to make zoom.

Comment: Thank you very  much. I check this as a valid response. But now I need in mobile when scrolling page over the map scroll page stop. ¿Is there a way of force two fingers over the map for move the map? That is the solution in google maps. I need avoid be intrusive when users are scrolling in touch devices.

Comment: @Falinsito if the solution works for you, you can tick the answer as accepted. and for the mobile you can create new question with more details

Comment: Please, as you recomend I create this new question for mobile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49427735/open-layer-3-how-force-move-the-map-with-two-fingers-in-touch-devices-for-avoi  days ago but still no solutions

Comment: @Falinsito Please edit your question there so it will be shown again in the beginning active section to get more attention. And it's better to edit it with more clarification (example from google maps)